# android take phone screen shot programmatically, outside of the app?

Tags: android

I want to take a screen shot of my phone programmatically, when the user touch some of the key in the phone. Also i want to save the image somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello You can Try to use This One google.code link [Click here](http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/) yet i have not test it but it will give some hint to you.and can Also Have to look in SO Question [Link Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/screenshot-android) here